# Jenkins return job status SUCCESS when the test failed

Tags: selenium, jenkins, gruntjs, protractor

I am automating my protractor integration tests using Jenkins. When some of the tests fails Jenkins weeps saying that the result was successful. This is my output:

```
24 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 64.079 seconds
Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 failed 1 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

Test failed but keep the grunt process alive.

Done, without errors.[39m
Terminating xvnc.
$ vncserver -kill :28
Killing Xtightvnc process ID 24369
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I don't know if my problem is selenium or grunt related.

Does any one know what can be the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this Jenkins job is not set up properly, I suggest you review your Job Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out the problem.

I am using "grunt-protractor-runner" library. It has an option call "keepAlive" and it was set to true. This caused the process to continue even is something was wrong and not passing the error code to grunt.

After set it up to false everything behave as expected.